# Android : Making a Lockscreen Transparent to reveal the background widgets

Tags: android, widget, transparent, lockscreen

I wish to have a Transparent lockscreen for my Android 2.3.3. I would like to be able to see my widgets and clock directly from the Lockscreen without having to unlock.

I have noticed that the background wallpaper is displayed, but not the widgets.

I think there should be some edits made in KeyguardViewMediator and KeyguardViewManager. Can anyone give me a clue on how this could be achieved?

Please don't suggest me any Third Party apps for this purpose. I would wish to recompile from sources, hence please let me know the code changes required.

Thanks!

Comment: Lockscreen is a "locked screen" - you can't see main screens, you only can add some to your lockscreen.
I think George's answer is correct

Answer (score 2):

The only option I've found is to install an app that lets you customise and put widgets on the lockscreen. However that drains the battery faster since they are working 24/7 now instead of only when you unlock your phone.